# onClick event for Image in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onclick

Is it possible add "onClick" function to an Image (a component of a canvas) in Unity ?

```
var obj = new GameObject();
Image NewImage = obj.AddComponent<Image>();
NewImage.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(a + "/" + obj.name) as Sprite;
obj.SetActive(true);
obj.AddComponent<ClickAction>();
```

How can I add action for "onClick" event?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Supposing that `ClickAction` is your script, you could implement the `OnClick` functionality in the following way:

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ClickAction : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{ 
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // OnClick code goes here ...
    }
}
```

The namespace `UnityEngine.EventSystems` supplies you with the `IPointerClickHandler` interface. When your image is clicked, the code inside `OnPointerClick` will run.

Comment: @Quicki You are welcome! If you have any further questions feel free to ask them. :)

Comment: Okay, so what am I missing here?  I've got an image, I've attached the 'click action' script to it, but it's not capturing the click event.

Comment: @PaulMouchet If the code does not work for you, you should consider asking a new question. My answer is almost 4 years old, some things might have changed, or your input system might be misconfigured.

Comment: Okay, will do.  I'm new to Unity, so I thought that perhaps I was just missing something simple.

Answer (score 27):

The answer before is in 5 years ago, huge things have changed. Though it might still work, it could be easier. So I answer this again.

What you only should do is add EventTrigger component to the object you want to click. And add Pointer Click event type.
[image: like this]

And then just add the script, it will work.(click "+", add the object your script attached, and select the function)

**Note:** This method only applies to object that within Canvas, in other words, the object must be an UI object, like an image as this question asked.

Comment: Thanks for this, as I'd have gone for the other answer as I'm still checking out and learning all the different Unity bits. Why has yours only got 4 votes? :).

Comment: @TilleyTech haha, maybe it's because I have just answer for 3 months. Btw, I'm glad my answer is helpful to you.