# ScrollView Level Menu on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview

I'm trying to create a ScrollView with inside images, the images are the levels in the game, and when the user choose a level(a image), he can click the button (like "PLAY") so doing that change the scene to the level selected.

And another thig...how i can do to the images still in the center of the scroll view?

Comment: So you want to know how to load levels with images and also I can't understand the second question. What do you mean by images still in the center?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your "question" is way to broad and sounds more like a "please do it for me" request. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back with one specific programming related question.

Comment: Meanwhile you can have a look at [VerticalLayoutGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html) and  [LoadSceneAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for how to do a scrollable list, covered in [this](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-image) tutorial.
Instead of putting buttons in it, you put your images in.
To detect clicks on the image, you add a script to your image containing the OnClick() method. (somthing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567303/onclick-event-for-image-in-unity))

I hope I could help you.

Maybe try to put little more effort in your research before asking questions.

Comment: `Instead of putting buttons in it, you put your images in. To detect clicks on the image, you add a script to your image containing the OnClick() method` an image and a OnClick method ... So basically  .. a button? ^^ Please note that you only posted links but didn't really explain how to do things. If the URL breaks for some reason your post will be useless. Please reproduce a complete valid answer here. Otherwise this should rather be a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will remind it next time. Unfortunately my Reputation is too low to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I will remove this Question, because i found how to do it...

Btw for the second question, i just create a script which i can make move to the center all the images/buttons/objects. And if you don't know why i'm doing this, it's for create like an animation to show much easier what button/object are you selecting..if you see an image return to the center of the scrollview, you will know that is your image.

I know... I don't, explain well what i want..but i'm new in this world of programming..